# Scrambler and key!

Tags: computer-puzzle

You are given three files.

One is a snippet from `scrambler.py` file:

```
from PIL import Image
from random import randint

if input("[E]ncoding or [D]ecoding?\n(default: decoding)\n") == "E":
    encode = True
    print("ENCODING: ")
else:
    encode = False
    print("DECODING: ")

if encode:
    file = Image.open(input("Image to scramble: "))
    pix = file.load()
    keyfile = open("scrambled.txt", "w")

    for x in range(file.size[0]):
        for y in range(file.size[1]):
            temp = pix[x, y]
            newx = randint(0, file.size[0] - 1)
            newy = randint(0, file.size[1] - 1)
            pix[x, y] = pix[newx, newy]
            pix[newx, newy] = temp
            keyfile.write(str(x * 7) + " " + str(y * 14) + " " + str(newx * 5) + " " + str(newy * 6) + "\n")
    file.show()
```

The second is a file called [`scrambled.txt`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kto5EhrbNdOor4oLd8bbuxDGFkeNH43j/).

The final is an image called `scrambled.png`:

[image: scrambled.png]

---

Who left this message for you?

---

***Note: Gareth! Give the people a chance, please!***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [image]
>  Trivially-reversible permutation

Comment: Why are all the colors distorted?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Probably because the image in the question was uploaded as a JPG, not a PNG (imgur automatically converts images above a certain size to JPG).